# How to create a service resource on chef that starts a custom script?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have script called "exec.sh" that i need to run in the background my linux node through chef similar through what one would do through the "nohup" command. I want to so this as a service on chef that I can start and stop. How would I achieve this?

This is what I have:

```
execute "exec" do
 user test
 group test
 command "nohup ./workdir/exec.sh &>/dev/null &"
 action :run
end
```

I would rather have it in a service like"

```
service "exec" do 
 user test
 group test
 action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

How do I achieve this so that I can create a service resource that can start-stop, and or enable, my exec script?

Comment: Before you can use the `service` chef resource to manage a process, it should be "converted" to a service. And this varies from sys-v, upstart, to systemd. Here is an example for [systemd](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6).

Comment: Yes, a `systemd_unit` chef resource to create the systemd service and a normal `service` chef resource to manage it is going to be the best approach on linux.